# How reliably can the current COVID-19 tests discriminate it from the common cold coronavirus strain?

Tags: covid-19

I am not a medical professional and was wondering if there is a chance the current COVID-19 tests can confuse it with the much less dangerous common cold coronavirus. If a person tests positive for COVID-19, what is probability of this person being infected by the common cold coronavirus strain as opposed to COVID-19?

Comment: There is PCR testing so very unlikely. Your test would not be certified as reliable.